# Magento 2 Place order before sending to Payment Gateway?

Tags: redirect, payment, magento2

I am developing a Payment Gateway which the payment will be done by redirecting the browser to the bank website and payment would be done there and after a success it will be redirected back to the website

I could be able to redirect using the JavaScript code in payment renderer successfully but the problem is that the order will **not be placed before the redirection** to the bank

How to make the order and get the **Order_ID** before sending the user to the bank

The following is my js Code that redirects the user to a sepecific controller that handles the redirection

```
        continueToMellat: function () {

                //update payment method information if additional data was changed

                $.mage.redirect(url.build('redirect/redirect'));
                this.selectPaymentMethod();
                setPaymentMethodAction(this.messageContainer);
                return false;

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: can you provide module link or source code

Answer (score 0):

I could be able to place order before redirecting by changing the code to the following, this will place the order before sending to the payment gateway
I am now trying to get the order id of which the user has just ordered

```
continueToMellat: function () {


                if (this.validate() && additionalValidators.validate()) {
                this.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(false);

                this.getPlaceOrderDeferredObject()
                    .fail(
                        function () {
                            self.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(true);
                        }
                    ).done(
                        function () {
                            self.afterPlaceOrder();

                            if (self.redirectAfterPlaceOrder) {
                                redirectOnSuccessAction.execute();
                            }
                        }
                    );
            }
                //update payment method information if additional data was changed

                $.mage.redirect(url.build('redirect/redirect'));
                this.selectPaymentMethod();
                setPaymentMethodAction(this.messageContainer);
                return false;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use the cart ID : getQuoteId() like used in

```
//vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/get-payment-information.js


define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
...
], function ($, quote, ...) {
'use strict';

return function (deferred, messageContainer) {
    var serviceUrl;

    deferred = deferred || $.Deferred();

    /**
     * Checkout for guest and registered customer.
     */
    if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
        serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/guest-carts/:cartId/payment-information', {
            cartId: quote.getQuoteId()
        });
    }
```

though the order increment Id can be reserved in server before passing to client processing :

```
__construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession){
    $this->quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
}

...

$this->quote->reserveOrderId();
$orderId = $this->quote->getReservedOrderId();
```